# select onemenu values willbe disaplyed in hashcode format in the data table

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i tried disply the roleid values from the Permissions pojo class into data table

here my problem it displays hash values insted of original values

my bean class is:

---

```
        <f:facet name="header">
                Role Details

                </f:facet>

        <p:column headerText="Roleid" sortBy="#{ps.roleid}">



        <p:selectOneMenu id="role_id" value="#{ps.roleid}" >

            <f:selectItems value="#{one.p}" var="vv" itemLabel="#{vv}"
                itemValue="#{vv}" />

        </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:column>
```

my pojo class is:

---

```
one.java
private String roleid;

private String object_type;

private int object_id;

private int below;

private int high;

private boolean self;

private boolean exclude;

public String getRoleid() {

    return roleid;
}

public void setRoleid(String roleid) {

    this.roleid = roleid;
}
public String getObject_type() {

    return object_type;
}
public void setObject_type(String object_type) {

    this.object_type = object_type;
}
public int getObject_id() {

    return object_id;
}
public void setObject_id(int object_id) {

    this.object_id = object_id;
}

public int getBelow() {

    return below;
}
public void setBelow(int below) {

    this.below = below;
}
public int getHigh() {

    return high;
}
public void setHigh(int high) {

    this.high = high;
}
public boolean isSelf() {

    return self;
}
public void setSelf(boolean self) {

    this.self = self;
}
public boolean isExclude() {

    return exclude;
}
public void setExclude(boolean exclude) {

    this.exclude = exclude;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show the `roleid` property as item label then just write code accordingly? Right now you're printing the whole object (which implicitly shows its `toString()` value) instead of the property.

Replace

```
itemLabel="#{vv}"
```

by

```
itemLabel="#{vv.roleid}"
```

That "hashcode format" is by the way just the default outcome of [the `Object#toString()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) which will be used if you don't have a `@Override public String toString() { ... }` in your custom class.